# Tailwind CSS not responding in the browser despite correct installation and import

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm encountering an issue with Tailwind CSS where it's not being applied in the browser, despite following the installation instructions correctly. I've also attempted to use regular CSS to import it, but it's still not showing up on my website.

Someone previously told me I don't have the CSS file in my head tag but don't know how to implement it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post pictures of text when you can post the text itself.

Comment: You import CSS using a `<link>` tags, almost exactly the way you have done with the icon.  It just gets a different `type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the CSS file (probably `src/index.css`) you have shown in 2nd image into `App.jsx` root application file.

*src/App.jsx:*

```js
import './index.css';

const App = ...
```